# Why isn't my SQL updating the format when it's changed/updated?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using SQL and I'd like to update the format and change it as updated.

Here is my SQL code:

```
create hey (
  symbol varchar(25),
  series varchar(25),
  open float,
  high float,
  low float,
  close float,
  last float,
  prevclose float,
  tottrdqty int,
  tottrdval float,
  timestamp string,
);

create table stock as select
  symbol,
  series,
  open,
  high,
  low,
  close,
  last,
  prevclose,
  tottrdqty,
  tottrdval,
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestap ,'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as updated
from hey;
```

The problem occurs when I create the stock table it shows the function in each column instead of getting changed as updated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. This is a Q&A site which helps developers all over the world. It does especially well in combination with google ([programming = googling stackoverflow](http://www.theallium.com/engineering/computer-programming-to-be-officially-renamed-googling-stackoverflow/)). But we need people who ask questions to ask them in a way that they can be found. So please think about your title. Change it in a meaningful way that a person with the same problem could find your question.

Comment: What do you mean "it shows the function in each column". What do you mean by "instead of getting changed as updated". Is `Hey` a table? Is there data in `Hey`? I don't understand what you are asking or what the problem is or what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just write `create hey` in the first line, how does MySQL know what to create?

You need to specify the table name, for example:

```
create <table-name>
```